# Running sudo via ssh on remote server

Tags: bash, ssh, sudo

I am trying to write a deployment script which after copying the new release to the server should perform a few sudo commands on the remote machine.

```
#!/bin/bash
app=$1
echo "Deploying application $app"
echo "Copy file to server"
scp -pr $app-0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar nuc:/tmp/
echo "Execute deployment script"
ssh -tt stefan@nuc ARG1=$app 'bash -s' <<'ENDSSH'
    # commands to run on remote host
    echo Hello world
    echo $ARG1
    sudo ifconfig
    exit
ENDSSH
```

The file gets copied correctly and the passed argument printed as well. But the prompt for the password shows for two seconds then it says "Sorry, try again" and the second prompt shows the text I enter in plain text (meaning not masked) but also does not work if I enter the password correctly.

```
stefan@X220:~$ ./deploy.sh photos
Deploying application photos
Copy file to server
photos-0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar                                         100%   14MB  75.0MB/s   00:00    
Execute deployment script
  # commands to run on remote host
  echo Hello world
  echo $ARG1
  sudo ifconfig
  exit
stefan@nuc:~$   # commands to run on remote host
stefan@nuc:~$   echo Hello world
Hello world
stefan@nuc:~$   echo $ARG1
photos
stefan@nuc:~$   sudo ifconfig
[sudo] password for stefan: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for stefan: ksdlgfdkgdfg
```

I tried leaving out the -t flags for ssh as well as using -S for sudo which did not help. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com) would be a big help here

Comment: For my use case I honestly doubt that. I had to come to grips with it and for just copying a jar to a specific location and restart the process...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with another solution: Create another file with the script to execute on the remote server. Then copy it using scp and in the calling script do a

```
ssh -t remoteserver sudo /tmp/deploy_remote.sh parameter1
```

This works as expected. Of course the separate file is not the most elegant solution, but -t and -tt did not work when inlining the script to execute on the remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do :

```
ssh stefan@nuc bash -s foobar <<'EOF'
echo "arg1 is $1"
echo "$HOSTNAME"
ifconfig
exit
EOF
```

Tested, work well.

### Notes :

- for the trick to work, [**use ssh key pair instead of using a password**](https://gist.github.com/sputnick-dev/65f023c2ac8c2318dcb2563199ec663a), it's even more secure
- take care of the place of your `bash -s` argument. Check how I pass it
- no need `-tt` at all
- no need `sudo` to execute `ifconfig` and better use `ip a`

Comment: As a side note, if OP is adamant on using password based authentication, they could use `sshpass`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In fact I am already using an ssh key pair. ifconfig unfortunately was only an example command (and actually needs sudo on Debian, otherwise the command is not found). I need to move a file where I need sudo for. Prepending sudo to ifconfig above yields  "sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified". Adding -t to ssh results in "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal". Adding a second t results in the behavior described in the original question above.

Comment: Up to you to use `-tt` if you need to pass password. If you want it passwordless, you have to configure `sudo` with `visudo` on the server side

Comment: I do not want to have it passwordless. And -tt unfortunately does not work.

Comment: So ssh to `root@nuc` to avoid the need of entering interactive mode while using **a script** (if ubuntu, you need a root password)